# Searching registered trademarks by edit distance to a specific name

Tags: scraping, research

I want to register a trademark, have 10-20 possible names such as `fiestafizz` (not a real name, only for illustration), and am conducting a search about similar-sounding names. (If a similar trademark is already registered in similar classes, the Intellectual Property Office has immediate grounds for refusal, resulting in waste of time and money.) For each candidate name, I want a software that gives the most similar names, ranked by [Levenshtein edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

I can search for variations on a name, say `f??stafizz` at the [WIPO](https://branddb.wipo.int/en/quicksearch) or the [EUIPO](https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/#/tmview), but there's a huge number of variations to search for to reach an edit distance of 4 or 5. I searched online for `python scraper trademark registrations edit distance` and found no tool of the sort. Commercial tools do this type of search, but it's not automated and very expensive ($3-6k per name), and they do not rank the results by similarity.

Is there a software tool or a Python package that does this type of scraping or search on existing trademarks by edit distance?

Comment: If anyone decides to build a script to search Trademarks, in addition to letter substitution, you may also want to include a "Sounds like" parameter in your search criteria.

Soundex is the most famous of these types of searches (here is a good explanation on Ancestry.com: https://support.ancestry.com/s/article/Searching-with-Soundex?language=en_US)

The Trademark search page includes something similar using Phonetic Equivalents (Section 201): https://www.altlegal.com/blog/how-to-search-using-the-usptos-new-trademark-search-tool/

Just something to consider